# I am not able to deserialize my json response in listview

Tags: arrays, json, serialization, soap, gson

This is my code of my class which gets the json response in "resp".

```
public class Caller extends  Thread {

    public CallSoap cs;
    public String resp, Blood_Group, City;
    ClassObj object;
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    public  void run() {

        try {
            cs = new CallSoap();
            resp = cs.CallGetDonorList(Blood_Group, City);

            object = gson.fromJson(resp,ClassObj.class);

            int a = 0;

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MainActivity.rslt=ex.toString();
        }
    }

}
```

resp has value like this:

```
[{
  "Donor_Id":1,
  "Donor_Name":"Rakesh",
  "Donor_ContactNo":9044234578,
  "Blood_Group":"A+",
  "City":"Lucknow"},
  {....}
]
```

and I have created a class to serialize these values as:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ClassObj {

    @SerializedName("Donor_Id")
    private int Donor_Id;

    @SerializedName("Donor_Name")
    private String Donor_Name;

    @SerializedName("Donor_ContactNo")
    private String Donor_ContactNo;

    @SerializedName("Blood_Group")
    private String Blood_Group;

    @SerializedName("City")
    private String City;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to deserialize an *array* of donor objects, not just a single one. As such, you'll need to specify the type correctly:

```
//declaration
ClassObj[] objects;

//deserialization
objects = gson.fromJson(resp,ClassObj[].class);
```

I would also strongly consider naming your classes and variables appropriately, i.e. `ClassObj` could be `Donor` and `objects` could be `donors`.

Comment: Thank you @Klaycon but still m receiving an error of gson:"{serializeNulls : false, factories:[Factory[typeHierarchy = com.google.gson.JsonElement, adapter = com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapter$29@5be63b6],.........]

Comment: Please post the full error and context in another question @sumbul khan